# Find volume: $(\frac{x}{5})^6+(\frac{|y|}{4})^7 < 1, (\frac{x}{5})^6+(\frac{|z|}{3})^\frac{42}{29} < 1$: stuck integrating. A better way?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, volume

Find volume of the body given by the following inequalities:
$$D=
\begin{cases}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^6+\left(\frac{|y|}{4}\right)^7 < 1, \\[1ex]
\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^6+\left(\frac{|z|}{3}\right)^\frac{42}{29} < 1.
\end{cases}
$$

These seem to be two intersecting cylinders of radius $1$.

Substitute
$$
x=5u^\frac{1}{3}, \\ y=4v^\frac{2}{7}, \\ z=3w^\frac{29}{21}.
$$

Then, multiplying by the absolute value of the Jacobian while moving to the new coordinates,
$$ \int \int \int _{D}dx \ dy \ dz = \int z'_w \ dw \int y'_v \ dv \int x'_u \ du = \int  dz(w) \int dy(v) \int dx(u) . $$

$$D'=
\begin{cases}u^2+v^2 < 1, \\[1ex]
 u^2+w^2 < 1.
\end{cases}
$$

To calculate, we need to bother with the bounds:

$$
\int_{-1}^1 dx(u) \int_{-\sqrt{1-u^2}}^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} dy(v) \ \int_{-\sqrt{1-u^2}}^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} dz(w) = \int_{-1}^1 2 * 3(1-u^2)^\frac{29}{21*2} dx(u) \int_{-\sqrt{1-u^2}}^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \ dy(v) = \int_{-1}^1 2 * 3(1-u^2)^\frac{29}{21*2} \ * \ 2*4(1-u^2)^\frac{2}{7*2} dx(u),
$$

and I am not sure if what I have done above was legal. Either way,

$$
2^4*3*5*\frac{1}{3}\int_{-1}^{1} (1-u^2)^\frac{5}{6}u^{-\frac{2}{3}} du,
$$

$$u:=\sqrt{t},$$

$$
\int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^\frac{5}{6} \ t^{-\frac{1}{3}} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} \ dt = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^\frac{5}{6} \ t^{-\frac{5}{6}} \ dt = \frac{1}{2} \ В \left( \frac{1}{6}, \frac{11}{6} \right).
$$

And here I am stuck. In classroom, we only did beta-gamma functions with integers as a way to help in calculation of similar integrals. I have no in-depth knowledge of beta-gamma functions. We'll need to solve a similar problem in class: it's time-restricting, and my approach seems swampy.

Is what was written above technically correct?

How do I calculate the last integral?

Is there a fast way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wanting to calculate the following *triple integral*:

$$
||\Omega|| := \iiint\limits_{\Omega} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
$$

where is it:

$$
\Omega := \left\{
(x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 
\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^6 + \left(\frac{|y|}{4}\right)^7 \le 1, \;
\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^6 + \left(\frac{|z|}{3}\right)^{\frac{42}{29}} \le 1
\right\},
$$

for *symmetrical reasons* we can reduce to the following calculation:

$$
||\Omega|| = 2^3\iiint\limits_{\Omega_{\text{sym}}} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
$$

where is it:

$$
\Omega_{\text{sym}} := \left\{
(x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 
\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^6 + \left(\frac{y}{4}\right)^7 \le 1, \;
\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^6 + \left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^{\frac{42}{29}} \le 1, \;
x \ge 0, \; y \ge 0, \; z \ge 0
\right\}.
$$

So, opting for the following *coordinate transformation*:

$$
\Phi : 
\begin{cases}
x = 5\,u^{1/3} \\
y = 4\,v^{2/7} \\
z = 3\,w^{29/21}
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \; \; \; \text{with} \; 
(u,\,v,\,w) \in \left[0,\,1\right] \times \left[0,\,\sqrt{1-u^2}\right] \times \left[0,\,\sqrt{1-u^2}\right]
$$

and Jacobian $J_{\Phi} = \frac{1160}{147}\frac{w^{8/21}}{u^{2/3}\,v^{5/7}}$, all this translates into the following calculation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
||\Omega|| 
& = 8 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} J_{\Phi}\,\text{d}u\,\text{d}v\,\text{d}w \\
& = \frac{9280}{147} \int_0^1 u^{-2/3}\,\text{d}u \int_0^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} v^{-5/7}\,\text{d}v \int_0^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} w^{8/21}\,\text{d}w \\
& = \frac{320}{7} \int_0^1 u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{29/42}\,\text{d}u \int_0^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} v^{-5/7}\,\text{d}v \\
& = 160 \int_0^1 u^{\color{blue}{-2/3}}\,\left(1-u^{\color{red}{2}}\right)^{\color{green}{5/6}}\,\text{d}u \\
& = 160 \int_0^1 \frac{1\color{blue}{-\frac{2}{3}}+\color{red}{2}\cdot\color{green}{\frac{5}{6}}}{1\color{blue}{-\frac{2}{3}}+\color{red}{2}\cdot\color{green}{\frac{5}{6}}}\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{5/6}\,\text{d}u \\
& = 80 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{3}\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{5/6} + \frac{5}{3}\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{-1/6}\,\left(1 - u^2\right)\right)\text{d}u \\
& = 80 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{3}\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{5/6} - \frac{5}{3}\,u^{4/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{-1/6} + \frac{5}{3}\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{-1/6}\right)\text{d}u \\
& = 80 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{3}\,\left(1-6\,u^2\right)\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{-1/6}\,\text{d}u + 80 \int_0^1 \frac{5}{3}\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{-1/6}\,\text{d}u \\
& = 80\left[u^{1/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{5/6}\right]_{u=0}^{u=1} 
+ 400 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{3}\,u^{-2/3}\,\left(1-u^2\right)^{-1/6}\,\text{d}u \\
& = 400 \int_0^1 \left(1-x^6\right)^{-1/6}\,\text{d}x \\
& = 400 \int_0^{\infty} \left(1+y^6\right)^{1/6}\,\frac{1}{\left(1+y^6\right)^{7/6}}\,\text{d}y \\
& = 400 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^6}\,\text{d}y \\
& = \color{gold}{\frac{400}{3}\,\pi}\,.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Notably, the simplicity of this result appears highly sensitive to the choice of exponents $6,7,42/29$. If I pick a different combination, the integral still appears to be solvable (according to Mathematica) but is expressed in terms of the Gamma function. This is not so surprising: the last integral is a beta function, but one which is mercifully simple.

Comment: @TeM Kindly explain how you did away with the absolute value as well as how you wound up with the $2^3$ multiple.